# Can't create new project in fresh Android Studio installation

Tags: android, ide, android-studio

I have just installed Android Studio 0.8.6 (with Android SDK) and I can't start a new project.
On "select form factors" screen, I have nothing to choose from:

[image: no choice available on form factors screen]

Update to 0.8.9 did not help.
I use OpenSuse Linux, if that matters.
I don't get any exceptions in terminal.
Both JDK and Android SDK seem to be detected by Android Studio.

Is that a known bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: That feels like a bug, though it's not a general Linux one, as my Ubuntu install of 0.8.9 works fine, even after today's updates.

Comment: Thanks. I've reported this issue [in Android project bug tracker](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77684).